# Need help to generate xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to get value of the attribute which is two positions behind of the attribute I know value of in the same element.

For example: I know the attributes which is typeID="3307", it is located in the element . The attribute I need value of is two positions to the left. How can I select that?

```
  ...
  <rowset name="skillBonusCollection" key="bonusType" columns="bonusType,bonusValue">
    <row bonusType="damageMultiplierBonus" bonusValue="5"/>
  </rowset>
</row>
<row typeName="Large Hybrid Turret" groupID="255" typeID="3307" published="1">
```

So again, how do I read the value of `typeName` attribute only having the `typeID=3307` in my hands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you already know the position of the `@typeID` I don't think you can do that. If you do, the xpath would be:

```
//row[@typeID='3307']/@*[position() = $typeIDPosition - 2]
```

But I think it would be much simpler and readable to do it without positions, since you know you want @typeName:

```
//row[@typeID='3307']/@typeName
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked like a charm